# Unable to invoke/call a Python method

Tags: python, class

can't get my class variables working properly,

```
class World:
  def __init__(self, size):
    self.size = size
    self.grid = []
    for i in range(0,size):
        self.grid.append([])
        for j in range(0,size):
            self.grid[i].append(0)
  def Display(self):
    for row in self.grid:
        print row

TheWorld = World(int(raw_input("Input world size(integer): ")))
TheWorld.Display
```

The problem is, the display function doesn't do anything, i think it's not referencing self.grid properly somehow. I input the world size as 0,10,100, doesn't make a difference. Any ideas ?? Thanks

Comment: Note that `range(0, size)` is no different from `range(size)`.

Comment: You should initialize `grid` using a [list-comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions): `self.grid = [[0 for unused in range(size)] for unused1 in range(size)]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not calling the function, you are merely referencing the function object. Try:

```
TheWorld.Display()
```

Answer (score 3):

Well that should be because you have not actually called the Display function. You have to say

```
TheWorld.Display()
```

for the function to be actually called.

Answer (score 1):

This is not VBA. I have to call the function using `()`:

```
TheWorld = World(int(raw_input("Input world size(integer): ")))
TheWorld.Display()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add braces to call the method:

```
TheWorld.Display()
```